# Node-Soap Cannot read property 'Body' of undefined

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap, node-soap

Using node-soap:

I'm trying to use this service : `http://services.resumeparsing.com/ParsingService.asmx?op=ParseResume`

I get a successful response when I query GetAccountInfo so I know my account/servicekey are correct: `http://services.resumeparsing.com/ParsingService.asmx?op=GetAccountInfo`

The error I'm seeing is: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Body' of undefined` when I try to use the ParseResume service.

Here's how I call ParseResume:

```
var buff_string = new Buffer(upload, 'base64')
var soap_args = {
   url:"http://services.resumeparsing.com/ParsingService.asmx?wsdl",
   args: {
      request: {
         AccountId    : myAccountId,
         ServiceKey   : myServiceKey,
         FileBytes    : buff_string,
         OutputXmlDoc : true,
         Configuration: myConfString
       }
   }
}

client.ParsingService.ParsingServiceSoap12.ParseResume(soap_args.args, function(err, result){
    if(err) console.log ( err )
    if(result) console.log (result)
})
```

As you can probably tell, I've never used SOAP before, any guidance is greatly appreciated!

edit: FileBytes is asking for a base64Binary string

Comment: Did you try `soap_args.args.request` instead of just `soap_args.args`?

Comment: Yes - same error. When I send a request without FileBytes I get an actual response from the service saying it needs to be included, when I include FileBytes with my base64 buffer I get the TypeError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changed

```
var buff_string = new Buffer(upload, 'base64')
```

to

```
var buff_string = (new Buffer(upload)).toString('base64')
```